# Entering -1 to terminate java program but should not assign to min value

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I was writing a java program to get the max, min, and total of the entered numbers. I want to terminate if the input is (-1) but in the programming, I wrote it assigning the -1 to the minimum value. What should I do to avoid it?

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max = 0, min = 0, mark=0, total=0, num=0;
    while(mark!=-1){
        System.out.print("Enter the mark of student (Enter (-1) to terminate) : ");
        mark = in.nextInt();
        if (mark>max){
            max=mark;
        }else if(mark<min & mark!=-1){
            min=mark;
        }else if(mark==-1){
            break;
        }
        total+=mark;
        num++;
    }
    System.out.println("Number number of student : " + num);
    System.out.println("Total Marks : " + total);
    System.out.println("Max Marks : " + max);
    System.out.println("Min Marks : " + min);
    System.out.println("Average Mark : " + (double)total/num);
}
```

}

### The inputs I added
10
20
30

The output
Number number of student : 3
Total Marks : 60
Max Marks : 30
Min Marks : 0
Average Mark : 20.0

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Gardener tried, still not working

Comment: Initializing `min = 0` is probably the culprit. Unless you get some negative mark in the input, `min` will stay `0`. Either initialize it to a value higher than any possible mark or to the first mark read.

Comment: Your title seems to mislead. I read it as -1 was assigned to the minimum, which doesn’t seem to happen. Can you rewrite and enhance clarity and precision?

Comment: Is 10, 20 or 30 less than zero? What about `min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` then any value entered would be less than the default minimum.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix it as @Ole V.V. told

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing `min = 0` was the culprit. I am now initializing it to the first mark read.

This working code for this.

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer ( press -1 to quit) : ");
        int mark = input.nextInt();
        int min=mark;
        int max=mark;
        int count=1, total=0;             
        while(mark != -1){
            if (mark>max) {
                max = mark;
            }else if(mark < min){
                min = mark;
            }
            count++;
            total+=mark;
            System.out.print("Enter an integer ( press -1 to quit) : ");
            mark = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("No of students: "+ count);
        System.out.println("Total Marks: "+ total);
        System.out.println("Minimum: " + min);
        System.out.println("Maximum: " + max);
        System.out.println("Average: " + (double)total/count);            
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time with this question.
Thanks, @Ole V.V. and @Gardener.